# Setting another variable with a regular expression in KSH

Tags: regex, ksh

I have a Korn shell script that I would like to change a variable based on another and a regex.

What I want to happen is to generate a variable value like below, but without calling sed:

```
$ echo 'orl,bdl,lap' | sed "s/,*orl//" | sed "s/^,*//"   
bdl,lap  
$ echo 'orl,bdl,lap' | sed "s/,*bdl//" | sed "s/^,*//"  
orl,lap  
$ echo 'orl,bdl,lap' | sed "s/,*lap//" | sed "s/^,*//"  
orl,bdl
```

I've tried variations of

```
export b="orl,bdl,lap"  
export a=${b}*(,*lap)
```

but usually get an error.  Is this possible?

I've seen this:

```
if [[ $var = fo@(?4*67).c ]];then ...
```

so it should work like it does with filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this?

`echo 'orl,bdl,lap' | cut -d"," -f3,2`

Change the `-f3,2` to other fields that you may need.

Also if you need better regex construction you could use `awk`, but then I need you provide better details to understand what transformation you need.

Comment: I would normally pipe out into sed or awk but I came across a note saying that you could do the regex internally and wanted to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `IFS`:

```
var='orl,bdl,lap'
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
array=($var)
newvar="${array[*]:1}"
IFS=$saveIFS
```

or

```
var='orl,bdl,lap'
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
set -- $var
shift
newvar="$*"
IFS=$saveIFS
```

Or using regex matching:

```
var='orl,bdl,lap'
pattern='^[^,]*,(.*)$'
[[ $var =~ $pattern ]]
newvar=${.sh.match[1]}
```

Comment: Cool - just the nudge i needed.

Answer (score 0):

here's the actual answer to the question as asked:

```
> print $KSH_VERSION
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
> b="orl,bdl,lap"
> a=${b/~(E),*orl}
> print $KSH_VERSION
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
>
> b="orl,bdl,lap"
>
> a=${b/~(E),*orl} a=${a/~(E)^,*}
> print $a
bdl,lap
>
> a=${b/~(E),*bdl} a=${a/~(E)^,*}
> print $a
orl,lap
>
> a=${b/~(E),*lap} a=${a/~(E)^,*}
> print $a
orl,bdl
>
```

see [the ksh93 manpage](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html) for details: you have to put together the material on patterns and pattern-lists under [file name generation](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#File%20Name%20Generation) with the material on search-and-replace variable expansions under [parameter expansion](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#Parameter%20Expansion) to figure this out completely.

note that while you can't directly apply multiple regexes in succession in a variable expansion (as you could have with `sed`, e.g. `sed "s/,*orl//;s/^,*//"`), you *can* put two variable assignments in the same statement, and they'll execute in succession, left to right.